# How to do "git commit --amend" using GitHub For Mac

Tags: git-commit, github-for-mac

Is the "commit --amend" feature not included in GitHub For Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [release notes](http://mac.github.com/release-notes.html), that feature doesn't seem to be available (idem for GitHub for Windows).

You could add that to the [list of issues for GitHub for Mac](https://github.com/baldwindavid/github-for-mac-issues/issues?page=1&state=open) (ofr recording) and using the [contact form](https://github.com/contact) (for action).

[Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183665/jonas) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399430/how-to-do-git-commit-amend-using-github-for-mac/13400715?noredirect=1#comment24162180_13400715) that there is a pending request for that feature:

[Issue 30: "git commit --amend" feature in github for mac](https://github.com/baldwindavid/github-for-mac-issues/issues/30)

Comment: For the record, the issue is here: https://github.com/baldwindavid/github-for-mac-issues/issues/30

Comment: @Jonas good point. I have added this link in the answer for more visibility, and I will be watching that issue.